# How can i know if a plugin i'm using from Git Hub has an update?

Tags: plugins, github

I want to know if there is a tool or a notification board that tells that a plugin cloned from git hub has an update.

Comment: What kind of a plugin? What language? How did you install it?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications/ You can have a notification by email about published releases.